# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Tags: python, discord

Делаю бота на discord.py. Нужно было проверить бота с нулевыми правами, но как только я это сделал, вылетает ошибка:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Вот мой код(Две команды, ну два разных варианта+ я обрезал не нужное )

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Навигация по командам бота Энни", colour=discord.Color.blue())
    embed1.add_field(name="Развлечения",
                     value="**!!annie** - Показывает всю информацию о данном боте\n**!!talk** - открывает информационный раздел, связанный с общением\n **!!anime** - Показывает аниме, которое можно посмотреть\n**!!serials** - Показывает сериалы, которые можно посмотреть\n**!!films** - Показывает фильмы, которые можно посмотреть\n**!!weather** - Открывает модуль связанный с погодой")
#обрезано
    embeds = [embed1]
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
    page = Paginator(client, message, only=ctx.author, use_more=False, embeds=embeds)
    await page.start()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason="причина не указана"):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="╔=============================╗", colour=discord.Color.red(),
                          description=f"{member.mention} был забанен по причине: {reason}")
    embed.set_footer(text="Операция прошла успешно")
    embed.set_image(url="http://s11.favim.com/orig/160603/anime-gif-itachi-uchiha-naruto-Favim.com-4374016.gif")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: дык написано ведь))) нет прав у бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании бота в его токене не было определённых прав, или когда его добавлял на сервер.

Поэтому и выходит данная ошибка.